# Cannot activate Self-service registration OKTA

Tags: okta, okta-signin-widget

I cannot activate self-service registration , it does not appear in my menu under "directory".
OKTA help center says that I should enable this Early Feature under "settings -> features" but I didn't find it
[Self-service registration in the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JCV5.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Okta Admin Dashboard Settings > Features you need to see these Early Access Features, in here you need to enable "Self Service Registration For Activation" [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15iLu.png).

After enabling this feature, you need to also allow registration on Profile Enrollment in the dashboard. To find the setting, Security > Profile Enrollment > Policy (that you use) > Edit > Self Service Registration > [Allow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsRJD.png)

After these configurations, you will be able to see the Sign Up option in the Sign In form: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnBNk.png)

For more informations you can see Okta's documentation : https://help.okta.com/en-us/Content/Topics/users-groups-profiles/usgp-self-service.htm

Comment: I can't find Feature tab in Settings.
Is it updated? Where can I find it?